# Prevent title change of NSPopUpButton at selection

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopUpButton without title. I set a NSImage for this popup button.
When I bind the Content value to an array with strings (to create a demo) the title of the popup button changes to the value of the array.

Is there a way to keep the image and prevent the title to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how `NSPopUpButton` works, it displays the selection. If you want to use it to trigger an action, set the type to "Pull Down". The first item in the array is the title.

> The NSPopUpButtonCell class defines the visual appearance of pop-up buttons that display pop-up or pull-down menus. Pop-up menus present the user with a set of choices, much the way radio buttons do, but using much less space. Pull-down menus also provide a set of choices but present the information in a slightly different way, usually to provide a set of commands from which the user can choose.